# Interpreting SIMPLS regression results in R

Tags: r, regression

I have done a SIMPLS regression in R but I am not sure how to interpret the results, this is how my function looks,

```
yarn.simpls<-mvr(Pcubes~X1+X2+X3,data=dtj,validation="CV",method="simpls")
```

and this is my results from

```
summary(yarn.simpls)


 X dimension: 33471 3 
        Y dimension: 33471 1
Fit method: simpls
Number of components considered: 3

VALIDATION: RMSEP
Cross-validated using 10 random segments.
       (Intercept)  1 comps  2 comps  3 comps
CV          0.5729   0.4449   0.4263   0.4175
adjCV       0.5729   0.4449   0.4263   0.4175

TRAINING: % variance explained
        1 comps  2 comps  3 comps
X         86.77    97.67      100
Pcubes    39.74    44.72       47
```

What i would like to know is, what is my coefficients? Is it the adjCV row under VALIDATION: RMSEP. The TRAINING: % variance explianed, is that like the significance of the variables? I just want to make sure i interpret the results correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The % variance is describing how much variation each ncomp captures from the x variables, and then the response variable, so it can be thought of as the relative ability of each of the ncomps to capture information in your data.

CV & adjCV are the values for the root mean squared error of prediction (RMSEP), which is giving you information about how well each ncomp model predicts the outcome variable. In your case, a model with 1 component seems to have the highest predictive power.

If you want coefficients for the underlying variables, use `coef(yarn.simpls)`. This will give you what the variable coefficients would be at each ncomp.